# Use multi ISO file in one Bootable CD/DVD

Tags: boot, multi-boot, iso-image, bootable-media

How can i have two or more ISO file that made for Boot (Bootable ISO), in One CD or DVD to boot ?
I have two different anti-viruses (Live Rescue) and i want to use them in one CD or DVD and switch between them from a DOS Command-Line (That is on the CD/DVD). How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A very roud-about way**

1. Download [YUMI Multiboot](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) and install the desired options onto a USB key.
2. Create an ISO of the USB
3. Burn that ISO to a disc.

I've done that before and it worked fine, but YMMV.

**edit**

I am yet to see a way to live swap from one of the options to another (i.e. drop to DOS and then back to a virus scanner).  You may want to roll your own rescue disc (various creators out there exist) and get all the linux tools you can.  You can do just as much (actually more) with a live linux disc than a windows dos prompt.

Comment: Is it just for Linux?? what if i have no any USB? or i just have to set option for USB ??

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri - Look through [the page](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to see if it meets your needs, there is a "List of Installable Live Linux Distributions" which includes some of the Live Antivirus suites and `Hiren's BootCD` which has many of those tools in it (and a semi cmd I think).